# How to send email using Outlook's SMTP servers?

Tags: email, go, outlook

I want to send an email using Outlook servers, but I'm getting an error `504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type`

Here's the snippet.

```
func sendEmail() {
    server := "smtp-mail.outlook.com
    port := 587
    user := "foo@outlook.com"
    from := user
    pass := "foobar"
    dest := "bar@gmail.com"

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, pass, server)

    to := []string{dest}

    msg := []byte("From: " + from + "\n" +
        "To: " + dest + "\n" +
        "Subject: Test outlook\n" +
        "OK")

    endpoint := server + ":" + port
    err := smtp.SendMail(endpoint, auth, from, to, msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

If instead of sending the email using outlook, I use gmail, it works fine.

In Python, I can send the email using outlook with the following code:

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.sendmail(from, to, msg)
    server.quit()
```

So I guess I'm missing something in my Go code. According to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail), `SendMail` switches to `TLS`, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, pass, server)
> ```

This is using the authentication method PLAIN. Unfortunately smtp-mail.outlook.com does not support this authentication method:

```
> EHLO example.com
< 250-AM0PR10CA0007.outlook.office365.com Hello ...
< 250- ...
< 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
```

Thus, only LOGIN and XOAUTH2 are supported as authentication methods.

> ```
> server.login(user, password)
> ```

Python supports LOGIN so it will succeed.

Golang smtp does not support LOGIN. But [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andelf/5118732) seems to provide a working fix by adding this missing authentication method.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: While this information is irrelevant to this specific question it is interesting though. Does this mean that 2FA is not supported with SMTP on O365 (because this is what XOAUTH2 is used for, LOGIN cannot do this) or how 2FA is done in this case?

Comment: That is correct - only LOGIN works with SMTP for the O365 (or on-prem Exchange) servers.